# Match integers against enum cases without a double match statement in Rust

Tags: rust, enums

So in Rust, i am trying to iterate over a vector of `u8`, and match them against cases of an enum. To do that, I set up the following code.

```
use std::io::prelude::*;

enum Byte {
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 2,
    D = 3
}

fn main() {
    let mut buf = Vec::<u8>::new();
    write!(buf, "\x01\x03\x02\x00");
    match buf[1] {
        Byte::A => println!("got A"),
        Byte::B => println!("got B"),
        Byte::C => println!("got C"),
        Byte::D => println!("got D")
    }
}
```

Assume the `println!` statements could be any form of behavior, such as determining what type comes next in the byte vec, etc.

However, this results in

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:16:9
   |
6  |     A = 0,
   |     ----- unit variant defined here
...
15 |     match buf[1] {
   |           ------ this expression has type `u8`
16 |         Byte::A => println!("got A"),
   |         ^^^^^^^ expected `u8`, found enum `Byte`
```

Then, if i try to cast the enum as a u8, with `Byte::A as u8` , a syntax error occurs. I am aware it's possible to convert the `u8` into a `Byte`, then match the converted `Byte`, but that requires two match statements, one to convert, then one to compare. I am looking for a way similar as in C/C++, to treat an enum case directly as an integer in Rust. Such that my original code can function.

If there is no way to do this, a way to match against named constants in a match statement would suffice.

Comment: Why do you need the enum ? You can match directky in the integer

Comment: `C/C++` mean nothing choice between C or C++

Comment: "I am looking for a way similar as in C/C++" This use of Rust `enum` is more like C++ `enum class`, which _can't_ be treated directly as an integer and has to be converted first. The equivalent C++ code would fail to compile too. If you want to get the equivalent of C `enum`, just use named constants.

Answer (score 4):

In short: you want to convert<sup>1</sup> an `u8` value to an `Byte`'s variant.

The problem is that there are values of `u8` that don't correspond to any variants of the `Byte` enum, for example, any `u8` value higher than `3` doesn't have a variant in `Byte` backing it (i.e., any `u8` value that matches `4..=255`).

How should such a conversion behave if you (try to) convert `7u8` to a `Byte`'s variant? Converting an `u8` value to an `enum`'s variant falls into the category of fallible conversions.

---

You could however implement the trait [`TryFrom<u8>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) for `Byte` for this kind of fallible conversion:

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;

impl TryFrom<u8> for Byte {
    type Error = ();

    fn try_from(val: u8) -> Result<Byte, ()> {
        match val {
            0 => Ok(Byte::A),
            1 => Ok(Byte::B),
            2 => Ok(Byte::C),
            3 => Ok(Byte::D),
            _ => Err(()),
        }
    }
}
```

Its associated function `try_from()` returns a `Result<Byte, ()>` instead of just `Byte` because the conversion may fail. Then, you just need extract the `Byte` (if any) from the returned `Result`:

```
match Byte::try_from(buf[1]).unwrap() {
    Byte::A => println!("got A"),
    Byte::B => println!("got B"),
    Byte::C => println!("got C"),
    Byte::D => println!("got D")
}
```

Or more concise, had `Byte` implemented `Display`, then you could just do away with the `match` above:

```
println!("got {}", Byte::try_from(buf[1]).unwrap());
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that performing a conversion in the other direction, i.e., from a `Byte`'s variant to an `u8` value, can be done trivially with the `as` operator, e.g., `Byte::A as u8`.

Comment: This still uses two match statements. Looking for a solution that only uses one match statement, or a different way to match against named constants.

Comment: I see your point on that some `u8` does not correspond to `Byte`, but I am looking for a way to use a definite `Byte` value like `B` as the `u8` value `1`. Such as in C++ where an enum can be used as an integer.

Comment: @JoshWeinstein What you want is the opposite: to use an integer as an enum.

Comment: @JoshWeinstein the second `match` is superfluous, it's just for consistency with your code. You can just implement `Display` for `Byte` and do `println!("got {}", Byte::try_from(buf[1]).unwrap())`. You just need a single `match` for performing the conversion.

Comment: The thing is the `println` statements are just an example, assume that the code for each case may be anything, like taking a slice of the next n bytes and interpreting them in some specific way, or other integer value dependent behaviors. If Rust allows you to put `A = 1, B= 2 ` in an enum definition, there should be some way to use the enum as those constant values.

Comment: Like the logic I am looking for would be similar to `Byte::A == 4`, where `Byte::A` would be converted to an integer value.

Comment: @JoshWeinstein converting a `Byte`'s variant to an `u8` value is trivial, e.g., `Byte::A as u8`. It's the other direction the one that may fail.

Comment: `Byte::A as u8` does not work in a match statement, results in syntax error.

Comment: @JoshWeinstein that's not how Rust enums work. Rust enums are type-safe sum types. What you want is named constants, that's what C enums are.

Comment: "If Rust allows you to put A = 1, B= 2 in an enum definition, there should be some way to use the enum as those constant values." there is, you can convert enum variants to the assocated value, not the other way around.

Comment: Incidentally [there is an RFC and an open issue for "const expression patterns"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76001) so on nightly you can use `const {Byte::A as u8}` as a pattern, but it could also crash your compiler so YMMV. Alternatively you can use [the inline-const crate](https://crates.io/crates/inline-const) to kinda sorta emulate this feature using macros. Otherwise you can in fact define e.g. `const A: u8 = Byte::A as u8`, and use *that* as a pattern, though the convenience is debatable.

Comment: There are crates that can generate the boilerplate for enum->integer conversions, e.g. [num_enum](https://crates.io/crates/num_enum). Perhaps that would be a solution if you'd like to avoid writing your own conversions.